# Use Mypy with Ruamel.yaml

Tags: mypy, ruamel.yaml

I am attempting to use MyPy with modules that use ruamel.yaml and Mypy cannot find ruamel.yaml even though Python has no problem finding it. I am puzzled because I can't find a module called YAML.py or class called YAML either, even though these statements work in Python:

```
from ruamel.yaml import YAML
yaml = YAML()
x = yaml.load()
```

What do I need to do to get MyPy to recognize ruamel.yaml?

Answer (score 8):

A workaround is to run without the incremental logic of mypy:

```sh
python -m mypy --no-incremental myfile.py
```

**Background**

There is a known issue in mypy, see [here](https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/7276).

In summary:

Something is not working with the incremental logic of mypy when it is encountering `ruamel`.

- When you run it once, all goes ok. This is the command:
  `python -m mypy myfile.py`
- Then, when you run it again, you get an error:

  `error: Skipping analyzing 'ruamel': found module but no type hints or library stubs  [import]`
- Then, when you run it again, it all goes ok
- etc.

Answer (score 1):

You should not be looking for a file `YAML.py`. The `YAML` in

```
yaml = YAML()
```

is a class that is defined in `ruamel/yaml/main.py`  and that gets imported into `ruamel/yaml/__init__.py` (both under site-packages). That is why you do:

```
from ruamel.yaml import YAML
```

(the alternative would be that there is a file `yaml.py` under the directory `ruamel`, but the loader/dumper is a bit too much to put in one file).

What might work if the above knowledge doesn't help you resolve things, is explicitly [set the global flag mypy_path](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/config_file.html?highlight=mypypath#global-flags) or the environment variable `MYPYPATH`. This has to include the directory in which the directory `ruamel` is located.

( I could not find it mentioned in the documentation, but from the source ( `mypy/build.py:mypy_path()` ) you can see that this is supposed to be a string that gets split on `os.pathsep` (which is the colon (`:`) on my Linux based system))

Comment: I tried this and mypy instructed me to remove the entry, I think because it is already specified in the standard PYTHONPATH since ruamel.yaml is installed in site_packages in a virtual environment on my machine. I suspect that mypy may not take cognizance of the code in your __init__.py file since it uses it's own code for finding Python packages and modules rather than using the standard Python methods. I am looking into the mypy source code right now to determine exactly how it does things.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue.

Even after setting MYPYPATH=./.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages

A temporary 'solution' is ignoring the missing import exception

> mypy --ignore-missing-imports